# Jquery-Table column filter dropdown list values in lowercase

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

One of the column called status in the table has dynamically created values like Good,Bad,Average in each rows.
But Column filter dropdown lists values like good,bad,average.

Not sure why its happening for sometime.

```
<table id="testtable" class="custom-popup">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="staus filter-select" data-placeholder="Show All">Status</th>
                 .
                 .
                 .

$(function () {
    /*** custom css only button popup ***/
    $(".custom-popup").tablesorter({

        widgets: ['zebra', 'columnSelector', 'stickyHeaders', 'sort2Hash', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            // target the column selector markup
            columnSelector_container: 
            // this option can either be a string (class applied to all filters) or an array (class applied to indexed filter)
            filter_cssFilter: '', // or []
            // if true, a filter will be added to the top of each table column;
            // disabled by using -> headers: { 1: { filter: false } } OR add class="filter-false"
            // if you set this to false, make sure you perform a search using the second method below
            filter_columnFilters: true
        }
    });
});
```

I am using jquery.tablesorter.js v2.22.2

Comment: You can modify the select text using the [`filter_selectSource` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource)

Comment: I want that to be a dropdown not search box.Can you tell me what is the reason for listing lowercase even the td has different case?

Comment: `filter_selectSource` *is* for populating a dropdown; It's showing lower case because the core [`ignoreCase`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#ignorecase) and [`filter_ignoreCase`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-ignorecase) options are `true` by default.

Comment: But If I add filter_selectSource  dropdown not coming its working like search box only.Table has dropdown filter for other columns too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need ignoreCase option in your parameters like this

```
$(".custom-popup").tablesorter({
        ignoreCase : false,
        ...
        widgetOptions: {
                filter_ignoreCase : true,
                ...
        }
});
```